# Increasing performance in Springboot application with Embedded tomcat server

Tags: java, spring-boot, multithreading

I am using SpringBoot 2.7.2 with Tomcat embedded server.
The application does not have front-end. It is primarily controller-service-persistence with PostgreSQL as database, exposing the server as REST APIs.
The application can be accessed by upto 5000 concurrent users and the Response time < 10msec.

For increasing max threads, there are options at Tomcat container level and then at Spring level :

```
server.tomcat.threads.max (default 200)
spring.task.execution.pool.max-size
```

My questions :

1. When a client request comes, a Tomcat thread is taken from threadpool to service the request. What about the threads within Spring?
2. For increasing application performance, which thread has a bigger role?
3. Tomcat embedded server has version 9.0.65. Does it have NIO enabled? If yes, how to confirm? If not, then is there a way to enable it for increasing performance?